# Print odd and even numbers with thread T1 and T2 respectively, If prime number comes, print in reverse order

Tags: java, multithreading

I recently had an interview with Morgan Stanley and was asked this question. I had to print all odd numbers when thread T1 is running and even numbers when T2 is running, but hey! there is more, If any **prime number** comes up then I had to reverse the order meaning now odd numbers with T2 and even numbers with T1.

Below is what I had tried but that guy looked at me like he wants to put me in jail for this solution. I'm new to multi-threading. There might be a way to establish the communication between multiple threads to achieve this using `notify()` and `wait()` methods. Could someone get me out of the jail?

```
public class MainClass extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for(int i=0;i<20;i++) {
            String tname = Thread.currentThread().getName();
            if(isPrime(i)) {
                switch(tname) {
                    case "T2":
                        if(i%2 != 0)
                        System.out.println(tname + " - "+i);
                        break;
                    case "T1":
                        if(i%2 == 0)
                        System.out.println(tname + " - "+i);
                        break;
                    default:break;
                }
            }else {
                switch(tname) {
                    case "T1":
                        if(i%2 != 0)
                        System.out.println(tname + " - "+i);
                        break;
                    case "T2":
                        if(i%2 == 0)
                        System.out.println(tname + " - "+i);
                        break;
                    default:break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public boolean isPrime(int num) {
        if(num <= 1) return false;
        if(num == 2) return true;
        for(int i=2;i<=num/2;i++) {
            if(num%i == 0)
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    public MainClass(String name) {
        super(name);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainClass t1 = new MainClass("T1");
        MainClass t2 = new MainClass("T2");
        t1.start();
        try {
            t1.join();//always keep it inside the try otherwise compile time error
        }catch(InterruptedException ie) {
            ie.printStackTrace();
        }
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

And here is the output.

```
T1 - 1
T1 - 2
T1 - 9
T1 - 15
T2 - 0
T2 - 3
T2 - 4
T2 - 5
T2 - 6
T2 - 7
T2 - 8
T2 - 10
T2 - 11
T2 - 12
T2 - 13
T2 - 14
T2 - 16
T2 - 17
T2 - 18
T2 - 19
```

Comment: I'd ask the interviewer why you are being asked to use two threads to process this few things. And why run the two threads one after the other?

Comment: You could cache the biggest prime already calculated.   
Then in your isPrime method instead of starting  
 i = 2   
you start   
i = biggestPrime.

Comment: I think you could also use extra Thread reference variables called evenThread and oddThread. You start them with oddThread = T1 and evenThread = T2. When it's a prime number you only invert the reference. Then you can pull the switch block outside of the if (isPrime()).

Comment: @Andreas Could you please provide an answer with better version of my code?